# How to alias the name of a column in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an eloquent model named Eloquent:

```
Products::where("actice", "=", true)->get()->toArray();
```

Now I want to add join-statement to it, I have defined a scopeQuery with:

```
public function scopeJoinWithTags($query)
    {
        return $query->leftJoin("tags", "tags.id", "=", "products.tag_id");
    }
```

Then our main query changes to:

```
Products::where("actice", "=", true)->joinWithTags->get()->toArray();
```

What I get is OK, it is what I do expect, but I want to change the name property of tags table to tag_name, how should I do that? I mean, i say somewhere in my query to:

```
 tags.name AS tag_name
```

So that in the final result array I do :

```
$result[$i]['tag_name'];
```

While now I have to :

```
$result[$i]['name'];
```

Comment: possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174837/laravel-4-eloquent-column-alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174837/laravel-4-eloquent-column-alias)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Simplest way to do this would be to add the fields you need to the `get()` method and alias the ones you want to rename there.

```
Products::where("actice", "=", true)
    ->joinWithTags
    ->get(['tags.name AS tag_name', 'products.*'])
    ->toArray();
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the second param? ''actice.*'` ? I have changed it to `products.*` and it works.

Comment: Oops sorry, yeah it should have been products.* 

It simply means to include all the fields of your product table.

Comment: This is the method I used, but it should be noted that other frameworks handle this natively with associative arrays. It's a pity this is left out of Laravel.

Comment: This works well. But what if i joined a few tables and i want to get every table's column? do you put '*' in the 'products.*'? cuz i tried that and didnt work...

Answer (score 20):

On Laravel 5.4 (I don't know if earlier version also apply) you can do that with the `select` method:

```
Products::where("actice", "=", true)
    ->joinWithTags
    ->select('tags.name AS tag_name', 'products.*')
    ->get();
```

At least for me this is cleaner.

Comment: how to rename the products table?

Answer (score 19):

There is also a cleaner way to achieve this

You can take advantage of laravel mutators

```
public function getTagNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['name'];
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is my go-to. Good for backward compatibility with an old column name.

Add the following to your model

1. `protected $appends = ['old_column_name'];`
2. ```php
   public function getOldColumnNameAttribute() {
     return $this->attributes['new_column_name'];
   }

   public function setOldColumnNameAttribute($value) {
     $this->attributes['new_column_name'] = $value;

     return $this;   
   }
   ```