# laravel Querying Relations name column (AS)

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

if i use `as` to name a column NULL is returned. I want to name the column like `(id_company as idC)`.

This is the code in question:

```
$entity = Entity::with(['typeEntity' => function ($q) {
    $q->select(['id_type_entity as ite', 'name_type_entity'])->get();
}, 'company' => function ($q) {
    $q->select(['id_company', 'name_company'])->get();
}])->get();
```

Without this, it works as expected.

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: how can i name the column like (id_company as idC) if i do that is return null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the `get()` method and assign the alias you want to use here.

An example from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958080/how-to-alias-the-name-of-a-column-in-eloquent):

```
Products::where("actice", "=", true)
    ->joinWithTags
    ->get(['tags.name AS tag_name', 'products.*'])
    ->toArray();
```