# Change column name in Laravel equivalent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am beginner in Laravel. I have this code:

```
$data = Term::whereDate('begin_date', '>=', $start)->whereDate('end_date',   '<=', $end)->get(['id','name','begin_date', 'end_date']);
```

This is work fine.

I need change my columns result: begin_date as start_date and end_date as finish_date

How can I change it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to alias the name of a column in Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958080/how-to-alias-the-name-of-a-column-in-eloquent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like this one

```
Term::whereDate('begin_date', '>=', $start)
   ->whereDate('end_date',   '<=', $end)
   ->get(['id','name','begin_date AS start_date', 'end_date As finish_date']);
```

Or by editing it in `select` method

```
Term::whereDate('begin_date', '>=', $start)
   ->whereDate('end_date',   '<=', $end)
   ->select('id','name','begin_date AS start_date', 'end_date As finish_date')
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to pass the aliases in with the get selection

```
->get(['id','name','begin_date AS start_date', 'end_date AS end_date']);
```

Comment: Fancy. I did not know this about the ```get()``` method!

Comment: It's actually a MySQL thing. You can alias columns when you select them as `SELECT column1 AS this_column, column2 AS that_column`. The GET method just passes that along.

Comment: I am aware of the SELECT way of aliasing like in STA's answer. But I did not know get() took an argument that is essentially the SELECT. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Have you just tried replacing those columns in the code you pasted?

```
$data = Term::whereDate('start_date', '>=', $start)->whereDate('finish_date',   '<=', $end)->get(['id','name','start_date', 'finish_date']);
```

Comment: Thank you. [{"title":"Testowe wydarzenie","start":"2020-07-31 08:00:00","end":"2020-07-31 09:00:00"}] - have this result. Is posible remove hour/minutes/second from result?

Answer (score 0):

You can name the columns inside get method on your query. Try this:

```
$data = Term::whereDate('begin_date', '>=', $start)->whereDate('end_date',   '<=', $end)->get(['id','name','begin_date AS start_date', 'end_date AS finish_date']);
```

Comment: Thank you. [{"title":"Testowe wydarzenie","start":"2020-07-31 08:00:00","end":"2020-07-31 09:00:00"}] - have this result. Is posible remove hour/minutes/second from result?

Comment: Yes, possible. This way inside get: ('DATE_FORMAT(begin_date AS start_date, '%d-%M-%Y')'). Or, after fetching the result simply use like this: $data->start_date->format('d-m-Y');