# Laravel PHP ALIAS on Model?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've been tackling on Laravel and I haven't found a few answers to minor questions.

Is there anyway that in the model I can create ALIASES for columns?

If not, I've been trying a few variations for my queries but none seem to give me what I want.

```
public function getEditHeader($adhID){
    return View::make('adventures.editHeader')
        ->with('adventureheader', AdventureHeader::find($adhID)->select('adhID', 'adhTitle AS title', 'adhDescription AS description')->get())
        ->with('adventuretypes', AdventureType::orderBy('adtDescription')->lists('adtDescription', 'adtID'));
}
```

I've tried many variants but I feel like i'm not comprehending what I'm actually attempting with Laravel. I just want my queries to come out with alias because i dont have my tables prefix in the form's input names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoever is looking to achieve ALIASES please take a look into this link:

[Laravel 4 Eloquent Column Alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174837/laravel-4-eloquent-column-alias)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `selectRaw` method:

```
AdventureHeader::find($adhID)
               ->selectRaw('adhID, adhTitle AS title, adhDescription AS description')->get()
```

Comment: Hello Joseph. I'm actually out of time to test it, although a friend of mine sent me this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174837/laravel-4-eloquent-column-alias Thank you for your answer I will try it tomorrow first chance I get and get back to this post.

Comment: The link I provided is also correct. What I wanted was more in the lines of model so it is more correct than yours although yours is also a viable way, thank you so much for your contribution.