# How to get specific column with custom column name on Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

Looking for a way to get specific columns from Laravel Eloquent with custom column names.

E.g. get **example_name** as **name**.

I am trying to replicate SQL Alias like `SELECT column_name AS alias_name` but without using custom attributes.

Here is and example query in Laravel:

```
Table::get(['column1', 'column2', 'column3'])->all()
```

And what I would like it to get would look something like this:

```
Table::get(['column1', 'column2 AS column4', 'column3'])->all()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 Eloquent Column Alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174837/laravel-4-eloquent-column-alias)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example in user model `email` as `emailAddress` u want to get  then in your user model do like that

```
protected $appends = ['emailAddress']; //add custom column here..

public function getEmailAddressAttribute()
{
     return $this->email;
}
```

or u can use by query like that

```
User::select('id','name','email as emailAddress')->get();

Table::select('column1', 'column2 AS column4', 'column3')->get()
```

for more detail read https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators

Comment: I was using 'get' instead of 'select', therefore it was not working for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @butaminas no worry